# Как сделать так что-бы музыка играла во всех активити]

Tags: java, android

Нужно сделать что бы музыка продолжала играть при переходе по всем активити.
Использую такой код для звуков

```
 MediaPlayer mediaPlayer = new MediaPlayer();
    mediaPlayer.setAudioStreamType(AudioManager.STREAM_MUSIC);
    MediaPlayer click = MediaPlayer.create(this, R.raw."Нужная музыка");
    click.start();
```

Comment: Android Studio это всего лишь среда разработки. Она не определяет, как будет воспроизводиться звук. А вам надо делать воспроизведение вне зависимости от того, какая Activity сейчас активна - перенести воспроизведение в службу (Service)

Answer (score 1):

Самый примитивный способ - это сделать статичным экземпляр класса, который отвечает за работу с аудио и с ним работать в любом Activity. Вот [пример](https://github.com/KostyaBakay/KBMP) простого музыкального плеера, который я делал. Это конечно же плохой способ и на самом деле желательно для этой цели использовать Service.